# Formkit - how to get a form schema

Tags: vuejs3, formkit

I started using FormKit and I would like to find the way to get the form schema from a form defined in the code.

```
<script setup>
    import '@formkit/themes/genesis'

    const createUser = async (fields) => {
        await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1000))
        alert(JSON.stringify(fields))
        console.log(fields)
    }
</script>

<template>
    <div><h2>My first form</h2></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <FormKit type="form" @submit="createUser" submit-label="Salva utente">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <FormKit type="text" name="nome" id="nome" label="Nome" help="Inserisci il tuo nome di battesimo" placeholder="Mario" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <FormKit type="text" name="cognome" id="cognome" label="Cognome" help="Inserisci il tuo cognome" placeholder="Rossi" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <FormKit
                        type="select"
                        label="What planet is the largest?"
                        placeholder="Select a planet"
                        name="planet"
                        :options="{
                            mercury: 'Mercury',
                            venus: 'Venus',
                            earth: 'Earth',
                            mars: 'Mars',
                            jupiter: 'Jupiter',
                            saturn: 'Saturn',
                            uranus: 'Uranus',
                            neptune: 'Neptune',
                        }"
                        validation="required|is:jupiter"
                        validation-visibility="dirty"
                        :validation-messages="{
                            is: 'Nope! Jupiter is the largest planet',
                        }"
                    />
                </div>
            </FormKit>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</template>
```

As I have some issue building the schema from scratch, I would like to use some test form to get the schema and look how it is defined. Then I will use it to understand better, do some tests and finally store the real final schema to db to generate form by form schema.

So my final question is: is there a way I can use to get the form schema?

Kind regards,
Matteo

Comment: just got the same question in mind. Did you find a way to solve it?